# execute function when onclick function is done

Tags: jquery, html

Im trying to troubleshoot this application.

Theres anchor tag with a

```
onclick="javascript: return ShowItemDiscussion();"
```

and thats on its separate js file.

Im trying to get a function to execute thats on a separate js file when that onclick is done loading.

I'm assuming its not working since my function that I want to execute loads when the document is ready, and since what im trying to target is not visible until the showItem is click on, its not working.

Is there a way to run a function when the other fully loads?

Comment: Make sure you are loading the separate .js file (where the function `ShowItemDiscussion()` is  ) on header or before the `<a>` tag

Comment: Considering javascript is single-threaded, you can say onclick="ShowItemDiscussion(); myNextFunction();" and it will execute them in order. If you have asynchronous processing in your first function, however, you will need to place the reference to the next function you want to call into the callback of the asynchronous operation

Comment: you can try aspect oriented programming in jquery for reference check this  https://github.com/gonzalocasas/jquery-aop,  http://crosscuttingconcerns.com/AOP-in-JavaScript-with-jQuery

Comment: @mhodges that could work, I will give that a try. the problem I dont have access to the source code, since its a pre-made third party application.But it does let you  run your own scripts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should be putting more code in your question so that you can get best possible answer. No offense i mean!
Second, you should not be writing INLINE JAVASCRIPT like that, it's a bad practice. 
You can do it this way:
**HTML:** `<a id="myBtn">Click Here</a>`


**JS:**

```
$(function){ //document ready function
  $("#myBtn").on("click", function(){
     // Do what you want to do here!
     callNextFunction(); //This would execute after above code has executed considering that there are no asynchronous calls
  });
}
```

Also, make sure that your OTHER JS FILE is loading properly.
All of your scripts should be either in `<head>` or at the very bottom of the `<body>`